# Card Sort Analysis using Excel (Agreement and Disagreement Matrices)

Tags: data-analysis, card-sorting

I'm trying to find way to tabulate the results of an open card sorting exercise.  We have about 50 cards total and need to pair that down so I'm hoping to crunch the numbers in excel to see where there was high/low agreement between cards.

I've found a couple of spreadsheets that do other forms of analysis, but none that do the matrix.  Does anyone know where I could find one?

Comment: I generally just use the one built into OptimalSort, but I know [Donna Spencer](http://rosenfeldmedia.com/expert/donna-spencer/) has [a Card Sort Analysis Excel template](http://rosenfeldmedia.com/books/card-sorting/#resources) available in the resources for her book (I'm not entirely sure it contains a similarity matrix).

Comment: I had looked at Donna Spencer's template, but it didn't include a matrix.  I searched a little more and it turns out, somebody made [a matrix that reads data from Donna's template](http://www.informoire.com/co-occurrence-matrix/).

Comment: NOTE: If you use the matrix in the link I posted above, please be aware that Sheet10 points at Sort1 rather than Sort10.  Ask if that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

built to work with Donna Spencer's spreadsheet

http://www.informoire.com/co-occurrence-matrix/

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit. As it is it's slightly cryptic. Furthermore could you copy and paste the relevant information into your answer?